# JSF page rendering twice?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

All of a sudden my JSF 2 is rendering every page twice (with Eclipse and Tomcat.) No matter how simple it is. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<h:body>
   <h:outputText value="What's going on?"></h:outputText>
</h:body>
```

is generating a result that looks like this:

> What's going on? What's going on?

If I put more complex stuff in there they also show up on the page twice. I tried restarting and all but no luck. So, what's going on?

## **Edit:**

Thanks for your answer everyone. r0ast3d I did change my web.xml to add a filter, and when I removed the entries the double vision disappeared. But I want the filter... The entries I had are like this:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>dontCache</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.company.auctions.ui.DisableCacheFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>dontCache</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

This is the doFilter method:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // place your code here

    System.out.println("DisableCacheFilter.doFilter CALLED");

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    // pass the request along the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any recent changes to web.xml / faces-config.xml ... or the renderer codes / jars ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is right there in your `doFilter` method. You are calling `chain.doFilter(request, response)` twice.